# How to set timer not to reset when page is reload (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, api, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

Here is my JavaScript code. I want to avoid resetting timer when the page is refreshed.

```
const startingMinutes = 1;
let time = startingMinutes * 60;

const countdownEl = document.getElementById('countdown');

setInterval(updateCountDown, 1000);

    function updateCountDown() {
        const minutes = Math.floor(time/60);
        let seconds = time % 60;
    
        countdownEl.innerHTML = `${minutes}: ${seconds}`;
    
        if (time>0) {
            time--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: save the data to LocalStorage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805408/localstorage-and-setinterval-with-multiple-tabs

Comment: Here is a working example:   https://jsfiddle.net/tLajobq1/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Store the current counter variable in local storage.

Hope this helps.